# Manifest multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android

How can I support all screen sizes in my manifest? I've got:

```
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

But it says xlarge is not valid. Any ideas what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not supplying anything for screen size. That is completely remove the `<supports-screens ... />` tag. If your application supports all screen sizes that's nice. You might want to consider using a different layout for horizontal and vertical orientation.

Comment: So if I remove the tag it will run on any device?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, it will. That is how I run mine as well.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute **android:xlargeScreens**  was introduced in API level 9. So I guess you are compiling againts lower API level. You should change the API level of your project to Android 2.3. I would recommend to develop your project for lower API versions and include **android:xlargeScreens**  atrribute only for you beta version(when your app is almost ready for release). So you'll be sure your project doesn't lack backward compatibility.